# Conditional Filter and aggregate in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table on sheet 1 that looks like the following:

| Class | Section | Name | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | A | Tom | 75 |
| 12 | B | Bob | 85 |
| 12 | A | Roy | 60 |

In another sheet (Sheet 2), I want to create another view that gives me ability to see average mark with optional filter of 'Class' and 'Section' Column.

I am trying to achieve this with the following IFS command in my Sheet 2 respective cell.

```
=IFS(AND(D2="All Classes",G2= "All Sections"), {result 1},  // No specific class or section chosen, should return average of all marks
AND(D2 <>"All Classes",G2= "All Sections"), {result 2},     // A specific class is chosen, should return average of all marks from that class
AND(D2="All Classes",G2 <> "All Sections"), {result 3},      // A specific section is chosen, should return average of all marks from that section
AND(D2<>"All Classes",G2<> "All Sections"), {result 4})     // A specific class and a section is chosen, should return average of all marks from that class and that section.
```

I am trying to figure out the respected result 1, 2, 3, 4 in the above command. **Tried with both Filter and Query, but none of them seem to be working for me.**

What built in function should I use?

Comment: should average be based on names? or names do not matter?

Comment: Names dont matter

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

Use this if `Class` column is numbers

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY(Sheet1!A:D,CONCATENATE("select D where A ",IF(D2="All Classes","is not null","="&D2)," and B ",IF(G2="All Sections","is not null","='"&G2&"'")),1))
```

Use this if `Class` column is strings

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY(Sheet1!A:D,CONCATENATE("select D where A ",IF(D2="All Classes","is not null","='"&D2&"'")," and B ",IF(G2="All Sections","is not null","='"&G2&"'")),1))
```